# Validate input textbox with image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 13 input text boxes simply to collect information from user.  I'm trying to add a little bit of logic that when user clicks next button check to see if input field is blank and if so place a X image after the textbox.  Where I'm getting up up at is if I put text in the box then it will not outline the box in red but still places an X after the form.

I've tried using the $.each() and $.filter()

Here is the js:

```
var invalid =  '<img src="css/Filtration/img/x.png" /> ';
$('.btn').click(function () {
    var inputs = $(":input").filter(function () {
    return this.value === "";
     });

    if (inputs.length) {
        $(inputs).css('border-color', 'red').after(invalid);
        console.log(inputs.length);
            }
 });
```

Here is some of the input text boxes not all :

```
<label>First Name:</label>
<input type="text" name="First Name" class="txtbox" id="firstName" /> 
<label>Last Name:</label>
<input type="text" name="Last Name" class="txtbox" id="lastName" /> 
<label>Email Address:</label>
<input type="text" name="Email Address" class="txtbox" id="email" />
<label>Company:</label>
<input type="text" name="Company" class="txtbox" id="company" />
```

Comment: can you post the complete HTML form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var invalid =  '<img src="css/Filtration/img/x.png" /> ';
$('.btn').click(function () {

    $(":input").each(function () {
        if($(this).val() == '' ){

            $(this).css({borderColor: 'red'}).after(invalid);
        }
    });
});
```

Note that if you had not previously set other border css parameters, the `color` may not work. So this pattern can take care of it in that case:

```
.css({border: '1px solid red'})
```

Now, `:input` is a bit broad and therefore inefficient. Therefore, its better to say:

```
$(':text', '#container').each(...
```

Where `#container` is, of course, the container of all your inputs.

Comment: still producing the same results.  Wondering how it is removing the border color but still placing the 'X' after the text box.

Comment: Ok. You mean the border-color is not applied, but the img is? If so, then try the current `{}` style I've edited.

Comment: If the `.css()` above will not work, then certainly it is being overridden by some other style declaration. It might help to inspect the textbox in the browser console. Just off the top of my head, check this by trying `'red !important'` in place of `'red`'.

Answer (score 0):

Please, consider use **jquery Validate**, you can see examples [here](http://jqueryvalidation.org/files/demo/)  and documentation [here](http://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/)

Comment: the page is set up containing a form with in a form.  That was my first choice to use validate

Comment: A form within a form is no valid html. The browsers rendering engine will ruin that structure.

Comment: Sorry @TroyBryant, Which page is set up containing a form with in a form?

Comment: Yeah. I was just going to ask that.

Comment: @deFreitas. In case you're yet to solve your issue, please see my latest edit regarding declaration of css `border` parameters.